# Why can this generic method with a bound return any type?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, generic-method

Why does the following code compile?
The method `IElement.getX(String)` returns an instance of the type `IElement` or of subclasses thereof. The code in the `Main` class invokes the `getX(String)` method. The compiler allows to store the return value to a variable of the type `Integer` (which obviously is not in the hierarchy of `IElement`).

```
public interface IElement extends CharSequence {
  <T extends IElement> T getX(String value);
}

public class Main {
  public void example(IElement element) {
    Integer x = element.getX("x");
  }
}
```

**Shouldn't the return type still be an instance of `IElement`** - even after the type erasure?

The bytecode of the `getX(String)` method is:

```
public abstract <T extends IElement> T getX(java.lang.String);
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_ABSTRACT
Signature: #7                           // <T::LIElement;>(Ljava/lang/String;)TT;
```

**Edit:** Replaced `String` consistently with `Integer`.

Comment: Java version is: 1.7.0_45 32 bit

Comment: CharSequence is Assignable to String .. what's the problem?

Comment: Just tested the original version (the one with `Integer`) with Java 1.8.0_31 - it does indeed compile.

Comment: It compiles with java 6 too. Strangely it seems to accept any return type. String str = element.getX("Y") works as well. And when you highlight the method in eclipse, it shows <? extend Integer> ? extends Integer IElement.getX(String)

Comment: Seems to pertain to using an interface as upper bound. Change to "T extends List", still compiles..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is actually a legitimate type inference*.

We can reduce this to the following example ([Ideone](http://ideone.com/JKR6Ke)):

```
interface Foo {
    <F extends Foo> F bar();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = null;
        String baz = foo.bar();
    }
}
```

The compiler is allowed to infer a (nonsensical, really) intersection type `String & Foo` because `Foo` is an interface. For the example in the question, `Integer & IElement` is inferred.

It's nonsensical because the conversion is impossible. We can't do such a cast ourselves:

```
// won't compile because Integer is final
Integer x = (Integer & IElement) element;
```

---

Type inference basically works with:

- a set of *inference variables* for each of a method's type parameters.
- a set of *bounds* that must be conformed to.
- sometimes *constraints*, which are *reduced* to bounds.

At the end of the algorithm, each variable is *resolved* to an intersection type based on the bound set, and if they're valid, the invocation compiles.

The process begins in [8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.1.3):

> When inference begins, a bound set is typically generated from a list of type parameter declarations `P1, ..., Pp` and associated inference variables `α1, ..., αp`. Such a bound set is constructed as follows. For each *l (1 ≤ l ≤ p)*:
>
> - […]
> - Otherwise, for each type `T` delimited by `&` in a [*TypeBound*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-TypeBound), the bound `αl <: T[P1:=α1, ..., Pp:=αp]` appears in the set […].

So, this means first the compiler starts with a bound of `F <: Foo` (which means `F` is a subtype of `Foo`).

Moving to [18.5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2), the return target type gets considered:

> If the invocation is a poly expression, […] let `R` be the return type of `m`, let `T` be the invocation's target type, and then:
>
> - […]
> - Otherwise, the constraint formula `‹R θ → T›` is reduced and incorporated with [the bound set].

The constraint formula `‹R θ → T›` gets reduced to another bound of `R θ <: T`, so we have `F <: String`.

Later on these get resolved according to [18.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.4):

> […] a candidate instantiation `Ti` is defined for each `αi`:
>
> - Otherwise, where `αi` has proper upper bounds `U1, ..., Uk`, `Ti = glb(U1, ..., Uk)`.
>
> The bounds `α1 = T1, ..., αn = Tn` are incorporated with the current bound set.

Recall that our set of bounds is `F <: Foo, F <: String`. `glb(String, Foo)` is defined as `String & Foo`. This is apparently a legitimate type for [glb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10), which only requires that:

> It is a compile-time error if, for any two **classes** (**not interfaces**) `Vi` and `Vj`, `Vi` is not a subclass of `Vj` or vice versa.

Finally:

> If resolution succeeds with instantiations `T1, ..., Tp` for inference variables `α1, ..., αp`, let `θ'` be the substitution `[P1:=T1, ..., Pp:=Tp]`. Then:
>
> - If unchecked conversion was not necessary for the method to be applicable, then the invocation type of `m` is obtained by applying `θ'` to the type of `m`.

The method is therefore invoked with `String & Foo` as the type of `F`. We can of course assign this to a `String`, thus impossibly converting a `Foo` to a `String`.

The fact that `String`/`Integer` are final classes is apparently not considered.

---

<sub>* Note: type *erasure* is/was completely unrelated to the issue.</sub>

<sub>Also, while this compiles on Java 7 as well, I think it's reasonable to say we needn't worry about the specification there. Java 7's type inference was essentially a less sophisticated version of Java 8's. It compiles for similar reasons.</sub>

---

As an addendum, while strange, this will likely never cause a problem that was not already present. It's rarely useful to write a generic method whose return type is solely inferred from the return target, because only `null` can be returned from such a method without casting.

Suppose for example we have some map analog which stores subtypes of a particular interface:

```
interface FooImplMap {
    void put(String key, Foo value);
    <F extends Foo> F get(String key);
}

class Bar implements Foo {}
class Biz implements Foo {}
```

It's already perfectly valid to make an error such as the following:

```
FooImplMap m = ...;
m.put("b", new Bar());
Biz b = m.get("b"); // casting Bar to Biz
```

So the fact that we can *also* do `Integer i = m.get("b");` is not a *new* possibility for error. If we were programming code like this, it was already potentially unsound to begin with.

Generally, a type parameter should only be solely inferred from the target type if there is no reason to bound it, e.g. `Collections.emptyList()` and `Optional.empty()`:

```
private static final Optional<?> EMPTY = new Optional<>();

public static<T> Optional<T> empty() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Optional<T> t = (Optional<T>) EMPTY;
    return t;
}
```

This is A-OK because `Optional.empty()` can neither produce nor consume a `T`.

Comment: The Problem might be that `T extends [interface]` implicitly means `T extends Object & [Interface]`. Since a String is an Object, the compiler doesn't report the issue.

Comment: @Radiodef - *Raw Types*!! That's was the phrase I was looking for!

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I can assure you there are no raw types anywhere in this Q&A right now. And if there were, a different thing happens anyway. We actually get an error. http://ideone.com/SeZ09H

Comment: Thanks a lot for the description of this cryptic part of the JLS to explain what is happening.

Comment: However, you can cast from `Object` to `(Integer&IElement)` :) or from `Number` etc.